# addition of 2 models as input to another (graph disconnected)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have two models, `model_A` and `model_B`. I want to do element wise addition with those two models and use the result as input to `model_C`. So, I have this code:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, BatchNormalization, \
    Activation, Input, Add
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def model_A(inputs):
    x1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    x1 = BatchNormalization()(x1)
    x1 = Activation('relu')(x1)
    
    x2 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(x1)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x2, name='model_A')
    return model
    

def model_B(inputs):
    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(f1)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=f2, name='model_B')
    return model

def model_C(inputs):
    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f1)
    f2 = BatchNormalization()(f2)
    f2 = Activation('relu')(f2)

    f3 = Conv2D(1, 3,  padding='same')(f2)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=f3, name='model_C')
    return model
    
def model_final(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))
    
    modelA = model_A(inputs)
    modelB = model_B(inputs)
    
    addition = Add()([modelA.output, modelB.output])
    
    modelC = model_C(addition)
    
    return Model(inputs, modelC.output)
    
a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 32, 32, 3))
b = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 32, 32, 3))
c = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 32, 32, 3))
    
model = model_final(32, 32, 3)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='mae',
              metrics=['mae'])
```

If I run the code, I receive `Graph disconnected` at `Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=f3, name='model_C')`. So, in order to solve this problem, I am doing:

```
def model_final(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))
    
    modelA = model_A(inputs)
    modelB = model_B(inputs)
    
    addition = Add()([modelA.output, modelB.output])
    
    inputs_C = Input((height, width, 32))
    modelC = model_C(inputs_C)
    modelC = modelC(addition)
    
    model = Model(inputs, modelC)
    return model
```

which compiles fine. But, I am not sure if this is right. If the logic of doing this is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you are creating a new input to C, while you should be using models A and B outputs for that.

I'd suggest either you create fully separate models, then you run tensors along them and create an overall model; or you don't create submodels and work directly with the tensors instead.

---

### Using submodels

This is better if you really want submodels for training them separately, dettaching them and using elsewhere, etc:

```
def model_A(height, width, channels):
    
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))

    x1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    x1 = BatchNormalization()(x1)
    x1 = Activation('relu')(x1)
    
    x2 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(x1)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x2, name='model_A')
    return model
```

```
def model_B(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels)) 

    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(f1)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=f2, name='model_B')
    return model
```

```
def model_C(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))

    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f1)
    f2 = BatchNormalization()(f2)
    f2 = Activation('relu')(f2)

    f3 = Conv2D(1, 3,  padding='same')(f2)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=f3, name='model_C')
    return model
```

Then you "run a tensor" through the models:

```
def model_final(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))
    
    modelA = model_A(height, width, channels)
    modelB = model_B(height, width, channels)
    modelC = model_C(height, width, channels)

    outputsA = modelA(inputs)
    outputsB = modelB(inputs)
    
    addition = Add()([outputsA, outputsB])

    outputsC= modelC(addition)
    
    model = Model(inputs, outputsC)
    return model
```

---

### Making a single model

This option can be easier to use when saving/loading and other things, but you wont be able to have separate models for other purposes.

Here you only return the outputs, not new models, and then make a single model.

```
def model_A(inputs):
    x1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    x1 = BatchNormalization()(x1)
    x1 = Activation('relu')(x1)
    
    x2 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(x1)
    
    return x2
```

```
def model_B(inputs):
    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(f1)

    return f2
```

```
def model_C(inputs):
    f1 = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same')(inputs)
    f1 = BatchNormalization()(f1)
    f1 = Activation('relu')(f1)
    
    f2 = Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same')(f1)
    f2 = BatchNormalization()(f2)
    f2 = Activation('relu')(f2)

    f3 = Conv2D(1, 3,  padding='same')(f2)

    return f3
```

The final model then uses the tensors to be built:

```
def model_final(height, width, channels):
    inputs = Input((height, width, channels))
    
    x2 = model_A(inputs)
    f2 = model_B(inputs)
    
    addition = Add()([x2, f2])
    
    outputs = model_C(addition)
    
    return Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel! If I return `x2` and `f2` as you said, and leave `model_C` as I already have, then running the `model_final` you gave me gives again `Graph disconnected`. I think we have to return `f3` also from `model_C` right?

Comment: @George, I completely updated my answer noticing it was flawed. Take a look, it uses two different approaches and avoid mixing the two.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! upv